# MySQL directory path name was changed /var/lib/mysql/mysql -> /var/lib/mysql/mm

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

On 5 March 2019 this directory was mysteriously renamed
from

`/var/lib/mysql/mysql`

to

`/var/lib/mysql/mm`

which ment that i was henceforth unable to restart or start the mysql 
service.

i am not aware how anything could have changed this.

I have not automatic updates to this Ubuntu installation and i never changed anything in mysql except for using it to read/write to the database.

```
VERSION="18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"

MySQL Server version: 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 (Ubuntu)
```

Was my system hacked? Or am i not aware of something changing it?

Anyone else had this happen?

Comment: should i post this to AskUbuntu instead?

Comment: Do you still need assistance with this question?

Comment: I changed it back. but still no clue as how this happened.

Comment: Someone made a mistake - about a year ago.  We hope all is well today, if not Open a New Question on an appropriate website, please.

Comment: Thanks I guess no one ever experienced this. No idea. Maybe the gremlins.